# Got stuck with List and retrofit2 and foreach

Tags: java, list, foreach, retrofit2

I am trying to use Retrofit 2.1.0 Upgrading from 1.9.0 On the response I am not able to run the markers I want to put on a map.
On Retrofit 1.9.0 it worked perfect but want to use an updated system.

```
Retrofit adapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl( AppConfig.URL_PINS )
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

MapPinsApiInterface pinsApiInterface = adapter.create(MapPinsApiInterface.class);
Call<List<MapPins>> pins = (Call<List<MapPins>>) pinsApiInterface.getStreams();
pins.enqueue(new Callback<List<MapPins>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<MapPins>> pins, Response<List<MapPins>> response) {
        if (!isAdded() || pins == null )
            return;

        int numMarkersInRainbow[] = {
            R.mipmap.homecenter,
            R.mipmap.shop,
            R.mipmap.marksilv,
            R.mipmap.markgold,
            R.mipmap.markgreen,
            R.mipmap.markoran,
            R.mipmap.itsyou,
            R.mipmap.no_gps
        };
        bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        for (MapPins pin : pins) {    <***** Here is my error ***>
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(pin.getLatitude(), pin.getLongitude()));
            options.title(pin.getName());
            options.snippet(pin.getDepth());
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(numMarkersInRainbow[pin.getMarker()]));

            Marker mkr = googleMap.addMarker(options);
            mMarkers.put(mkr.getId(), pin.getSiteid());
            bounds.include(new LatLng(pin.getLatitude(), pin.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
```

In the line: `(MapPins pin : pins) {`

I get an error

> for each not applicable to type 'retrofit2.call'

I am sure I am overlooking something. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `retrofit2.Response` instance that you get, and from it you can get the [body of the response](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#body--) which is a `List<MapPins>`:

```
for (MapPins pin : response.body()) {
    // ...
}
```

But you should also check that the [response was successful](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#isSuccessful--):

```
if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
    // handle
}
```